# Data Scrubbing In EXCEL

Tags: excel, text, extract, data-scrubbing

This might be an easy one for all of the computer wiz out here! I would like to extract a string of characters in a EXCEL text box. The dataset is kind of messy, there is space, characters, and other text which I do not need.  For example:

I need to take ABC12345D1 out of "ABC ABCABC12345D1"

```
                             "ABC,ABCABC12345D1"
                             "KOhn!ABCABC12345D1"
                             "ABCABC12345D2 ABCABC12345D1"
                             "ABCABC12345D1ABCABC12345D1"
                             "MCDONALDABCABC12345D1"
```

But that is just one of the identifier I have to extract out. I wish there is a formula I can drag and pull down to the rest of the column.

So, the ABCABC12345D1 is made of

_ _ _ The first three character is an ID

_ _ _ _ _ The second part is the location tag

_ _ and the least past is whether it is on or off ( I can live by if that canoot be extracted.

Now I tried to taking the right 8 or 10 characters, and taking all the space out, but is there a clearer way on how to pull this data?

Answer (score 0):

Regex?

```
Function Regex(Cell)
    Dim RE As Object

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    RE.Pattern = "(\w{6}\d{5}\w\d)"
    RE.Global = True
    RE.IgnoreCase = True
    Set Matches = RE.Execute(Cell) 

    For Each res In Matches
        Regex = Regex & "," & res
    Next res
    Regex = Mid(Regex, 2)
End Function
```

Open VBA editor with ALT + F11.
Insert -> Module
Copy paste the code above in to the module window.
Close VBA editor.

In Excel sheet write `=Regex(A1)` to activate the function.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! Is there a easier way to do this? I am assuming this is VBA?

Comment: Yes this is VBA. Didn't see that you had not taged VBA. Sorry about that... I can make it a UDF? That way you can use it as a formula. Say if text is in A1, you should be able to in B1 write `REGEX("A1")`and it will return the part you want. Is that OK for you?

Comment: You kind of have to use regex as (I guess) it's not always ABCABC... With regex you declare what to look for, I wrote a regex for six characters, five digits, one character and one digit, in that order. If it sees that, no matter what the characters or digits it's a match

Comment: Thanks so much, I have to dig a little bit, never used REGEX before!

Comment: I will update my answer to morrow, I'm in bed now. I will make it a UDF and explain how to use it, give you the basics of regex. But you need to tell me what you want to do with the matches. I can find the pattern, but what to do with it. Just post it in the cell? What if there is more than one? As in line 3 and 4? What then? Comma separate them?

Comment: @KevinLiu you have not yet answered me what to do with the matche, so I made an example you can try. Remember to save the workbook as an macroactivated workbook now (xlsm)

Comment: Hi Andreas, Thanks for the update. So, I am getting the notion of the REGEX, but to build this deeper, how can I do this for a group of ABCABC12345D1. What if I am looking for BCDEFGHIJM2,and 10,000 different version of that string?

Comment: What is the common between the strings? Are they always the same lenght? Always a character first? Always a number last? Basically, how do YOU know this is the correct string or not? There must be some "rules" to it? Although this page is php, the regexpatterns are the same http://www.phpliveregex.com/

Comment: so the common element is that it always start with a letter, and it is 8 characters long. There might be add on to create more distinct identifier for the string. For this example the length is all the same.

Comment: `(\w[\w|\d]{7})` should work as a pattern then. It matches any character and 7 char or digits. But this also means that words that is not supposed to be matched may get matched as the regex is so wide.